# Cassandra Rails not able to do more then one column filter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, cassandra, cequel

Rails Cassandra not work with filter more then one column.

my modal

```
class Template 
  include Cequel::Record
  key :id,:int,index:true
  column :u_id,:uuid,:auto=>true
  column :user_id, :int,index:true
  column :code_type,:text,index:true
  column :name, :text
  column :code_text, :text
  timestamps
end
Template.where(:code_type=>"job_html_template",:user_id=>1).allow_filtering!

Cequel::Record::IllegalQuery: Can't scope by more than one indexed column in the same query

I am using  cequel (3.0.0)
```

Can some one please help me what's wrong with this ?

Comment: https://github.com/cequel/cequel/issues/208....  In below link comment says only one secondary index is allowed in filter  https://github.com/cequel/cequel/blob/master/lib/cequel/record/record_set.rb

Comment: https://github.com/cequel/cequel/pull/353/commits/db696301e4dfa01cbcf67d9366e20bb4c165760c comment here says `Available as of Cassandra 3.6`

Comment: @ undefined_variable i have install latest version of Cassandra 3.11 still geting same error